# Method to convert an associative array into an indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have an associative array with indexed sub-arrays each containing associative arrays which contain content and an index. So like this (in PHP):

```
$assoc_arr = 
array("second" => array(
                       array("position" => 4,
                             "content" => "Valiant"),
                       array("position" => 5,
                             "content" => "Hail")
                      ),
      "first" =>  array(
                       array("position" => 0,
                             "content" => "Hail"),
                       array("position" => 3,
                             "content" => "Victors"),
                       array("position" => 2,
                             "content" => "the"),
                       array("position" => 1,
                             "content" => "to")
                      )
);
```

I want to put all of those into an indexed array where their index is their "position" in the associative array. So final array should be:

```
Array ( [0] => Hail [1] => to [2] => the [3] => Victors [4] => Valiant [5] => Hail )
```

Currently, I'm merging all of the arrays inside the highest level array, then sorting it by each of those sub-array's positions, then creating an indexed array by pushing the content in order onto a new array. As so:

```
$pos_arr = array_merge($assoc_arr["second"], $assoc_arr["first"]);
usort($pos_arr, function($a, $b) {
  return $a["position"] >= $b["position"] ? 1 : -1;
});

$indexed_arr = array();

foreach ($pos_arr as $elem) {
    array_push($indexed_arr, $elem["content"]);
}
```

It seems like there must be a better way to do this! Can anyone think of one?

The data is coming from a poorly structured XML document which I can't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$idxar=array();
foreach ($assoc_arr as $subar)
  foreach ($subar as $item)
    $idxar[$item['position']+0]=$item['content'];
```

will work, if your input data is flawless.

**Edit**

If you need the keys not only to be numerically correct, but also in the correct order, you must suffix this with `ksort($idxar)`

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution:

```
<?php

$assoc_arr = 
    array("second" => array(
        array("position" => 4,
              "content" => "Valiant"),
        array("position" => 5,
              "content" => "Hail")
        ),
    "first" =>  array(
        array("position" => 0,
              "content" => "Hail"),
        array("position" => 3,
              "content" => "Victors"),
        array("position" => 2,
              "content" => "the"),
        array("position" => 1,
              "content" => "to")
      )
);

$order = array('first','second'); // this helps you create your own sort. E.g. position1, position2, etc
$arr = array();

foreach($order as $ord) {
    if(isset($assoc_arr[$ord])) {
       $arr = array_merge($arr, $assoc_arr[$ord]);
    }
}

$finalArray = array();

foreach($arr as $a) {
    $finalArray[$a['position']] = $a['content'];
}

ksort($finalArray);

print_r($finalArray);
```

and a fiddle that works for you [here](http://3v4l.org/EdLaD)